# Eclipse installer "Java for Windows Missing"

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to install Eclipse for use with java, but when I try to run the installer, a browser window opens and I get this:

[image]

I do have both the JDK and JRE installed, and the path is set correctly. The version is 1.8.0, and the update number is 65. I need to start coding for a school project, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you by any chance download the 32 bit version of Java?

Comment: what is the OS version you are having whether 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: It says the browser can't find java. Restart the computer, or just don't worry about it. Download with the download button and run the installer. Should be fine.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem. Solution: Download & install the Windows-x64-version of the **J**ava **D**evelopment **K**it instead of the Windows-x86-version.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I solved installing Java 32 bits! (I have 64bits).

Answer (score 1):

Just download Oracle JDK 1.8 - that is one of the links you got below message u mentioned. Dont worry about that message.